# Why we need isolation in ACID?

Tags: mysql, database, acid

I am learning ACID, but not quite understand what is the difference between atomic and isolation.

From my understanding, if a transaction is atomic, that means the integrity of transaction-related data is written to DB when the transaction is succeeded, and not when failed.

**so why we need isolation?**

It can not be seen by others when failed for sure if atomic is guaranteed !?

Comment: The thorough wiki article on [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) refers to the wiki article on [Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)), which covers the concept in detail. What exactly needs clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Atomicity means that a single transaction is either completely executed or not at all executed. So for example if you have two account rows and you want to transfer money from one account to the other, you would see an increase to the amount of the one account a decrease to the amount of the other account or no change at all.

Isolation means that independent transactions do not interfere. So if you have multiple concurrent transactions in the same account rows you can be sure that each transaction is executed in isolation of the others. So if you have multiple transfers in the account table concurrently the results would be the same as if they were serially processed.